# call a code when done playing in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcp, tcpclient

I got a `tcp server` in `JAVA` and a class called `Client` among the unity scripts.
`Client` is a `singleton` that connects to the server at its `constructor`. When I press the play button it connects to the server but when I press again to stop the game the client is not disconnects automatically so when I run the game again it gets stack because he tries to connect from a computer he already connected. I tried to disconnect at the `destructor` but it never been called. how can I do it? I also tried to implement `IDisposable` but I do not know if you need to call it or the `garbage collector` calls it (for me it is not).
this is the client's code (`read` `write` and `loop` are not important for the question but I left it in case someone wants it):

```
using Assets.Scripts.Tools;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Client : System.Object, IDisposable{
    private TcpClient tcp;
    private Stream stream;
    private IClientCallback callback;
    private Thread recvThread;

    private static Client instance = null;

    public static Client Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Client();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private Client()
    {
        Init();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        Log.D("Init the client");
        tcp = new TcpClient();
        tcp.Connect(Main.IP, Main.PORT);
        stream = tcp.GetStream();
        recvThread = new Thread(loop);
        recvThread.Start();
    }

    public void setCallback(IClientCallback callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    // recving loop
    private void loop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Message msg = Read();
            if (callback != null)
            {
                callback.Callback(msg);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.E("callbackPointer is null, msg not handheld");
            }
        }
    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        tcp.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }

    // read a message from the server (will wait until a message is recved
    private Message Read()
    {
        try
        {
            int val;
            string res = "";
            do
            {
                val = stream.ReadByte();
                res += (char)val;
            } while (val != Code.END_MESSAGE && val != -1);
            return new Message(res);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            Log.E("Could not read from the server, disconnecting");
            throw new System.Exception("could not read from the server");
        }
    }

    // Write a message to the server
    public void Write(Message msg)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.D("Write:", msg.getDebug());
            stream.Write(msg.getBytes(), 0, msg.getBytes().Length);
            stream.Flush();
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            Log.E("Could not send message to the client");
            throw new System.Exception("could not write to the server: " + msg.getCode().ToString() + msg.toString());
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Log.D("never been called");
    }

    ~Client()
    {
        Log.D("never been called");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer I edit my question

Comment: maybe this helps? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-playmodeStateChanged.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `OnApplicationQuit()` callback function and disconnect from your tcp server or call your `disconnect()` method within there. This callback will run right before the application closes, both in the editor and in a built standalone player.
[OnApplicationQuit()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html)